# Gaussian Process Classifier and specifying kernel

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I am using scikitlearn's gaussian process classifier and either I don't think I understand how the kernel is used (more likely), or there is an error in the module (less likely). In short, the behavior is different when I specify the kernel and when I don't, even in cases where I specify the default kernel. Furthermore, when I fit a model to data not specifying the kernel, I cannot access the fit results, but "scores" for the fit appear reasonable. Here is an example of the problem using the commonly available learning iris data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = np.array(iris.target, dtype=int)

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

gpc_default =  GaussianProcessClassifier().fit(X, y)
gpc_default.score(X,y) #result is 0.82

kernel = 1.0 * RBF([1.0]) 
#my goal here is to specify the kernel explicitly, but use what I thought was the default kernel.
gpc_specifickernel =  GaussianProcessClassifier(kernel=kernel).fit(X, y)
gpc_specifickernel.score(X,y) #result is 0.8266666667
```

Two questions:

1) Why are these scores different? The inputs are the same.... right?

2) gpc_specifickernel.kernel_ has the best-fitting kernel values. In this case those are:
CompoundKernel(9.18, 0.913, 2.5, -0.26, 2.98, 1). However, gpc_default.kernel_ holds nothing interesting. More precisely, its value is CompoundKernel(). Why the difference? Also, when I use the default kernel, how to I access the best fitting parameters?